# Uploading android application to app store with Admob ads

Tags: android

I have just finished creating my android application and have created a Google Admobs account to create ads on my app. I downloaded the SDK and am currently displaying a test ad on my application. Now that I know it works how do I get an Ad ID that is not a test ad? The website says that I must select my app from a list of apps on the Play Store but I have yet to upload my app because I want it to be uploaded with a real ad id. How can I upload my app for the first time with live ads?

I know there is an option to create an ad id for an app that hasn't been uploaded yet but Admob says that I am not allowed to put a live ad id into an application that is in development. Is my application still considered in development or can I use this ad id and put it into my app and then upload the app to the Play Store? Or do I have to upload my app, get an ad id and then re-upload my app with the live ad?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new app by creating the store listing first. That might be enough to get an admob id. You could upload the apk at a later stage.